# Correctly animating an Android ImageView (possibly using a Matrix)

Tags: android, animation, matrix, android-imageview

So, I have a Layout that contains a `Button` and an `ImageView`. When you press the button the ImageView should slide out from the button like I just pulled down a rolldown curtain (bushing other views below it down). Basically what the image below show. When you press the button again the ImageView should, unlike the gif, smoothly animates up again.

[image: Button+ImageView blinds].

Using [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13984525/367204) I've managed to animate the height from 0 to full size but in the wrong direction. I set the scaleType to "Matrix" and the default behaviour when setting the height is to show the part from the top down to [height].

For the animation I'll need the opposite. So if I would set the height to 50dp it would show the bottom 50dp. Then I can move the ImageView down at the same time it's being revealed, thus giving the rolldown curtain effect.

I've looked throught all the different layout and view options and found nothing that seems to do this. So I'm guessing I need to specify the transformation matrix. I looked through the android.graphics.Matrix class but it's a little but too complicated for me. I simply have no idea how to use it.

If there is another, easier, way to do this then that would be fantastic but if not then I really need help with the matrix.

I'm also including the code here:

**The Rolldown View XML**

```xml
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sliding_accordion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/acc_image"
        android:contentDescription="@string/accord"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:layout_below="@+id/acc_button"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/acc_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**The implementation in code.**
(Note, the MyCustomAnimation class is a copy-paste version of the class [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13984525/367204))

```
//Called from all constructors
private void create()
{
    final Context context = getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.widget_accordion, this, false);

    final Button theButton = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.topic_button);
    final ImageView accordionView = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.sliding_accordion);
    accordionView.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);

    theButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if (accordionView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
            {
                MyCustomAnimation a = new MyCustomAnimation(accordionView, 1000, MyCustomAnimation.COLLAPSE);
                height = a.getHeight();
                accordionView.startAnimation(a);
            }
            else
            {
                MyCustomAnimation a = new MyCustomAnimation(accordionView, 1000, MyCustomAnimation.EXPAND);
                a.setHeight(height);
                accordionView.startAnimation(a);
            }
        }
    });

    this.addView(layout);
}
```

Comment: seems that if the final height is H and you set the height in your animation to h, then you should "skip" first (H-h) pixels, with matrix you can do it with preTranslate

Comment: I have no idea how to use the Matrix. None what so ever.

Comment: you get the matrix with ImageView.getImageMatrix() or so then ytanslate it, btw did you try to call View.
offsetTopAndBottom() in your animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took a long time perfect. But I managed to do it after a lot of experimenting.

I animate the margins of the drawer but because of the unexpected behavior of negative margins the button that opens the drawer can not be positioned on top.

When the drawer is closed the XML looks like so:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/accordion"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.animationtest.drawer.Drawer
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/topic_drawer"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <com.animationtest.drawer.Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/topic_btn"
        android:layout_marginTop="58dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then when the button is pressed the top_margin of the drawer is increased until it has come to whatever position is needed (in this case drawerHeight - someOffset).

I used android.view.animation.Animation to animate the widget my applyTransformation function looks something like this (Note that mLayoutParams are the drawer params):

```
@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    int valueDifference = Math.abs(startValue - endValue);
    float valueChange = interpolatedTime * valueDifference;

    if(currentState.equals(State.COLLAPSED)) {
        // is closed and I want to open it
        mLayoutParams.topMargin = Math.round(interpolatedTime * valueDifference);
    }
    else {
        // is opened and I want to close it
        mLayoutParams.topMargin = valueDifference - Math.round(interpolatedTime * valueDifference);
    }

    drawerView.requestLayout(); //this is my drawer
}
```

Finally, to hide the top of the drawer as it moves, I overrode my DrawerView's dispatchDraw method to looks like so:

```
@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    float height = getHeight();
    float top = height - ((LayoutParams) getLayoutParams()).topMargin;

    Path path = new Path();
    RectF rectF = new RectF(0.0f, top, getWidth(), height);

    path.addRoundRect(rectF, 0.0f, 0.0f, Path.Direction.CW);
    canvas.clipPath(path);
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
}
```

**One final note:**
Because of the Button's position one would need to set the widgets margin as a negative number for it to align correctly in a list or layout. In this case it would have to be -58dp.

Comment: This is not clear code enough, where are that overloaded functions? and how to call them?

Comment: Which functions do you mean applyTransformation and dispatchDraw? If so then you call neither of them directly if I remember correctly. It's been 4 years so I don't recall. But as stated applyTransformation is overidden in your view.animation.Animation extending class and dispatchDraw is overwritten in your View.