# How get height of the a view with gone visibility and height defined as wrap_content in xml?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a ListView with visibility=gone and height=wrap_content, and i need its height to can make an animation of expand.

I already tried it:

```
view.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
int height = view.getMeasuredHeight();
```

and

```
v.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
int height = view.getMeasuredHeight();
```

and

```
v.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
int height = view.getMeasuredHeight();
```

But it returned me a lesser value.

I am trying to do this after onResume.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The only way that i found was setting the width of the my view from width of a visible header view, then the below code returned me the right value.

```
int widthSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(headerView.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
int heightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
v.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
int height = v.getMeasuredHeight();
```

Answer (score 7):

```
view.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        int height = view.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
});
```

This worked for me. The method "post" makes sure the view is already added to the screen.

Answer (score 4):

There is only one efficient way to do that if you want to animate height of a view whose visibility is `gone`

First add this in xml of hidden view

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

then thats how you can set it to animate

```
yourView.layoutTransition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING)
```

Android will animate any layout change on that specific view

Answer (score 2):

When an object is gone, it no longer is part of the layout.  Maybe you mean to set your object to invisible, in which case you'll probably get a sensical value

Comment: I can not define it as invisible, because it will give up space on the screen.

Comment: So how can it return any height if it's not occupying any space?  You'll first need to calculate its height while it's not "gone".  Gone objects shouldn't have any height

Comment: you can try to get the number of items in the list, and then you'll be able to calculate its height

Comment: Is that each item can have a different height, i don't have how know tha total height.

Comment: Instead of Visibility.GONE, set the height & width to 0. So it has the same effects of GONE but when you measure it will give you correct results.

Answer (score -3):

This works for me

```
view.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
int height = view.getMeasuredHeight();
```

Comment: Pretty sure you are not supposed to use the LayoutParams constants here.